# Execute code upon Android app update

Tags: android

In my Android application I have some shared preferences, and one of them should not be used in my next release. However, it's value should be used in another shared preference. I could just be lazy and ignore that but then the user must make some settings after update in order for the application to work as it should. So i want to do this during update of application, in other words, take the existing value from the shared preferences and put it in the new shared preferences, this should be done one time only after update.

This is what I have in mind, but I don't know if it's the best practice:

```
public class UpgradeHandler extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
            // Make my shared preferences data migration
            // Other stuff to be done once after upgrade

            // Store to shared prefs that first time has passed
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the mechanism to handle update actions could be put in a usual class extending `Activity`, but It's crucial for my app that this shared preferences handling is done after update because the shared preferences that should be updated may be used in a `BroadcastReceiver` any time the application is installed. And if I have understood this correctly then a class extending `Application` and it's `onCreate` method is always called before any activities, broadcastreceivers, services and so on. Having my update handling in such a class should in my case ensure that my preferences handling is always executed afterupdate but before any activities or broadcastreceiver gets called. Is this correct?
My other question is if I go for a solution such as this, is it then correct to name the shared preferences variable to firstTime, I mean I cannot use it next time my app updates if I need to run something once, firstTime is then false. Wouldn't it be better practice to name shared preferences used for this in some pattern like `firstTime_version`?

I hope you understand my questions, at the bottom I just want to know the best handling of code that needs to be executed after application update.

Thanks!

Comment: The best thing is to have a variable in your shared preferences holding the last version used. Every time you start the app, you compare this bit of information with the current package version.

Comment: @Merlevede, okey that's a nice little tip that I definitely will use. Simple and clean solution, however do you know if classes extending Application` will run it's `onCreate` before any `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`and so on?